# Converting Smarty 3 templates to Twig 2, a few questions

Tags: twig, smarty

I am converting some Smarty 3 templates over to Twig just to familiarize myself with Twig as it appears that Smarty 3 is being sparsely maintained (security issues haven't been fixed in releases).

There are a few different things in some of these Smarty templates that I haven't been able to figure out how to do with Twig yet:

This just lets us abstact the actual form code out of the loops so that if someone needs to edit the forms they dont have to go into the loops and mess with that.

```
{function editform zoneid='' zonename=''}
 ...html stuff that uses zoneid and zonename
{/function}
{function delform zoneid='' zonename=''}
 ...html stuff that uses zoneid and zonename
{/function}
{foreach from=$zn_array key=k item=val}
<tr><td>{val}</td><td>{editform zoneid=$k zonename=$val}</td><td>{delform zoneid=$k zonename=$val}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
```

Any idea how to make 'functions' in templates that can use 'variables' sent to them later in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [macros](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html):

```
{% macro editform(zoneid, zonename) -%}
    Calling editform, zoneid is {{ zoneid|default('') }} and zonename is {{ zonename|default('') }}.
{%- endmacro %}

{% macro delform(zoneid, zonename) -%}
    Calling delform, zoneid is {{ zoneid|default('') }} and zonename is {{ zonename|default('') }}.
{%- endmacro %}

{% import _self as macros %}


{% for k, val in zn_array %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ val }}</td>
        <td>{{ macros.editform(k, val) }}</td>
        <td>{{ macros.delform(k, val) }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

When `zn_array` is `['first', 'second', 'third']`, the above produces this:

```
<tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>Calling editform, zoneid is 0 and zonename is first.</td>
    <td>Calling delform, zoneid is 0 and zonename is first.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>second</td>
    <td>Calling editform, zoneid is 1 and zonename is second.</td>
    <td>Calling delform, zoneid is 1 and zonename is second.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>Calling editform, zoneid is 2 and zonename is third.</td>
    <td>Calling delform, zoneid is 2 and zonename is third.</td>
</tr>
```

[See TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/hsutgx)

---

Some notes from the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html):

- Default argument values are defined by using the [`default` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) in the macro body
- Macros can be defined in any template, and need to be "imported" before being used
- To import macros from the current file, use the special `_self` variable for the source (this is said in the [documentation of the `import` tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/import.html))

Note also that I used `{%-` and `-%}` (instead of just `{%` and `%}`) in strategic places to [control whitespace](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control) so that the resulting HTML looks cleaner.

---

You can change the `import` statement slightly so that you can omit the `macros.` prefix when calling the macros:

```
{% from _self import editform, delform %}

{{ editform(k, val) }}
{{ delform(k, val) }}
```